# grep from list of keywords

Tags: shell-script, shell, grep, variable

Over the past couple of days I've been trying to dig through directories of files to report on files containing key words.  Through the help of other users showing me the correct syntax for `grep` and `sed`, I’ve come up with the following solution which has worked well. Unfortunately, it’s a bit repetitive and I'd like to refactor it.

```
echo "<HR><BR><B><h2>Search for Keyword:  KeyWord1<BR></B></h2><ol>"  >> temp.txt
grep -lr -Fiw 'KeyWord1' * | sed -e 's|.*|<li><a href="http://&">&</a></li>|'  >>  temp.txt
echo "</ol>"   >> temp.txt 

echo "<HR><BR><B><h2>Search for Keyword:  KeyWord2<BR></B></h2><ol>"  >> temp.txt
grep -lr -Fiw 'KeyWord2' * | sed -e 's|.*|<li><a href="http://&">&</a></li>|'  >>  temp.txt
echo "</ol>"   >> temp.txt 

echo "<HR><BR><B><h2>Search for Keyword:  KeyWord3<BR></B></h2><ol>"  >> temp.txt
grep -lr -Fiw 'KeyWord3' * | sed -e 's|.*|<li><a href="http://&">&</a></li>|'  >>  temp.txt
echo "</ol>"   >> temp.txt
```

I would like to produce the same results as the output generated by the above, but eliminate the clutter. Please advise on how to properly achieve something like the following:

```
Var myList = "KeyWord1, KeyWord2, KeyWord3"

while myList; Do
    echo "<HR><BR><B><h2>Search for Keyword:  $myList<BR></B></h2><ol>"  >> temp.txt
    grep -lr -Fiw '$myList' * | sed -e 's|.*|<li><a href="http://&">&</a></li>|'  >>  temp.txt
    echo "</ol>"   >> temp.txt 
; done
```

Comment: I am using sh on OS X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess was pretty close. 
You can do

```
for w in 'KeyWord1' 'KeyWord2' 'KeyWord3'
do
    echo "<HR><BR><B><h2>Search for Keyword:  $w<BR></B></h2><ol>"  >> temp.txt
    grep -lr -Fiw "$w" * | sed -e 's|.*|<li><a href="http://&">&</a></li>|'  >>  temp.txt
    echo "</ol>"   >> temp.txt
done
```

As a matter of style, I would change that to

```
for w in 'KeyWord1' 'KeyWord2' 'KeyWord3'
do
        echo "<HR><BR><B><h2>Search for $w:  KeyWord1<BR></B></h2><ol>"
        grep -lr -Fiw "$w" * | sed -e 's|.*|<li><a href="http://&">&</a></li>|'
        echo "</ol>"
done  > temp.txt
```

Your version will append this new content to a pre-existing `temp.txt` file. 
If that’s what you really want to do,
change the `>` back to a `>>`. 
After that, it is (infinitesimally) more efficient
to open `temp.txt` for writing once for the entire loop
rather than three times for each keyword.

P.S. It just occurred to me
that you have probably written `<html><head>…</head><body>`
to the output file before you do this,
so of course you *do* need this to append to that pre-existing content.

Comment: And David, please fix your HTML: `"<hr/><br/><h2>Search for keyword: $w</h2><br/><ol>"` (lowercase tags, removed broken `<B>` inside `<h2/>`, moved `<br/>` after `</h2>`)

Answer (score 0):

Hi David — I'd add a comment to G-Man's answer but I don't have the points.

Just wanted to add that with a recursive grep, you probably want to specify a directory or directories to search, not a wildcard, so something more like
`grep -lr -Fiw "$w" . …`
instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but wildcard is ideal as I'm scanning a large volume of directories.

Comment: Larry’s point is that ```grep -r … .``` is pretty much equivalent to ```grep -r … *```.